# Having trouble with login and register on android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on an android app and want to be able to do registration and login.  I followed an online tutorial but am having problems and I can't figure out how to fix it.  This is my first android app as well.  Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.cs309.gotoclass.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.cs309.gotoclass.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new     DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreenStudent.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

    public void LoginHome(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenStudent.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

public void LoginGuest(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenGuest.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

But I think the problem is in my JSONParser class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

And here is the error log that I have been getting

> 12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:62)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:55)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   12-01 10:47:45.995: E/AndroidRuntime(21570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thank you for any help that you guys can offer!

Update:

I think I am on the right track with AsyncTask but am still not there so any help would be appreciated!

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

//JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            //String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            //String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            new RegisterTask().execute();
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}

class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
int success;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();

    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    try {
        int success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            // DATABASE HANDLER
            // user successfully logged in
            // Store user details in SQLite Database
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                    getApplicationContext());
            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

            // Clear all previous data in database
            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_UID),
                    json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
if (success == 1) {
        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
}else{
    //Some Error

 }
}
}
}
```

And the error log...

> Blockquote

12-02 20:45:23.140: W/dalvikvm(28208): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception            (group=0x415e62a0)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.RegisterActivity$RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:89)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at com.example.cs309.gotoclass.RegisterActivity$RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-02 20:45:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28208):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not make a network request on main thread.

```
 JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
```

Use Threads, Handlers / AsyncTask instead.

Refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)